# Closing Python files while using cv2

Tags: python, opencv

Apologies in advance for the probably easy fix, I am a college student learning c++ and am using python for the first time on a personal project.

I am writing a program that extracts the title from a media file inside a directory or subdirectory, then looks to see if there are any strings that match. If there are then it compares their resolution, and deletes the lower resolution file. If they are both the same resolution, it deletes the larger file size. All of it is working, with the exception of deleting files. When I try to, it throws an error saying the files are in use. After doing some research, I learned that it was because I have the files open inside the code, preventing them from being deleted. My problem is that I don't know what variable I need to close, or the appropriate way and location to do so.

```
import os
import cv2
import PTN
import json

array1 = [os.path.join(r,file) for r,d,f in os.walk("E:\Python Test Environment") for file in f]

for x in range(0, len(array1)):
    print(array1[x])

array2 = array1[:] #The colon tells it to directly copy rather than do a link

for x in range(0, len(array2)):
    array2[x] = (json.dumps(PTN.parse(array2[x])))
    array2[x] = json.loads(array2[x])['title']
    head, array2[x] = os.path.split(array2[x])
    del head

y = len(array2)

for x in range(0, len(array2)):
    if array2[x] == "":
        break

    for i in range(x, y-1): #Set to x+1 so that it does not compare against the current file
        i = x + 1

        if array2[i] == "":
            break

        if array2[x] == array2[i]:
            print 'Match found!'
            print array1[i]
            print 'Matches: '
            print array1[x]

            with open(array1[x]) as f: #tried to include this to prevent error, doesn't seem to stop it
                capture1 = cv2.VideoCapture(array1[x]) #Open the video
                ret, frame = capture1.read() #Read the first frame
                resolution1 = frame.shape #Get resolution
                f.close()

            with open(array1[i]) as f: #tried to include this to prevent error, doesn't seem to stop it
                capture2 = cv2.VideoCapture(array1[i]) #Open the video
                ret, frame = capture2.read() #Read the first frame
                resolution2 = frame.shape #Get resolution
                f.close()

            if resolution1 > resolution2:
                print array1[x]
                print "Is higher resolution than"
                print array1[i]
                print "Would delete: "
                print array1[i]
                os.remove(array1[i])
                array1[i] = ""
                array2[i] = ""

            if resolution2 > resolution1:
                print array1[i]
                print "Is higher resolution than"
                print array1[x]
                print "Would delete: "
                print array1[i]
                os.remove(array1[x])
                array1[x] = ""
                array2[x] = ""

            if resolution1 == resolution2:
                print "equal"
                if os.path.getsize(array1[x]) <= os.path.getsize(array1[i]):
                    print "Would delete: "
                    print array1[i]
                    os.remove(array1[i])
                    array1[i] = ""
                    array2[i] = ""

                if os.path.getsize(array1[i]) < os.path.getsize(array1[x]):
                print "Would delete: "
                print array1[x]
                os.remove(array1[x])
                array1[x] = ""
                array2[x] = ""
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you include the stack trace that shows the error? It includes the failing line so we know what to look at. Much of the code isn't relevant to the problem... can you boil that down to a small example?

Comment: As an aside, `with` clauses like `with open(array1[x]) as f:` close the file when you exit the block so `f.close()` is not needed.

Comment: try adding `capture1.release()` and `capture2.release()` and see if that helps

Comment: Thank you both for the help! @jdigital was right, I needed to add 'capture.release()' and then it worked!

Comment: i've posted that as an answer, please mark it as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `capture1.release()` and `capture2.release()` to release the resources used by the `VideoCapture` instances